# Perl one line removes spaces

Tags: perl

I pieced together this one line to change the values in a csv file. It works perfect except that it removes all the spaces. If someone could explain what I'm doing wrong I would appreciate it.

```
    perl -pne 's/\s+(-?\d+\.?\d*)/$1>100?1000:$1/ge
```

Comment: You need to explain what you are trying to do in order to get help.

Comment: Try `perl -pne 's/(?<=\s)(-?\d+\.?\d*)/$1>100?1000:$1/ge`

Comment: Why are you using both `-p` and `-n`?

Comment: Don't ask the OP why, explain why that's not needed.

Comment: @LenJaffe Good point. Added to my answer.

Comment: You have our gratitude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Everything* matching the LHS of your regex

```
\s+(-?\d+\.?\d*)
```

will be replaced. That includes the whitespace matched by `\s+`. You can use a zero-width look-behind assertion as Matt suggested:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\s)(-?\d+\.?\d*)/$1>100?1000:$1/ge' file
```

or the special `\K` form, which will "keep" everything before the `\K`:

```
perl -pe 's/\s+\K(-?\d+\.?\d*)/$1>100?1000:$1/ge' file
```

Note that both `-p` and `-n` loop through every line of your input file(s), so you only need one or the other (although `-p` overrides `-n` if you do specify both). I used `-p` because it prints each line automatically. Details in [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Comment: Why was this made a wiki ?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I made it a wiki because it's essentially Matt's comment in answer form.